# MySQLi prepared statement format

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm creating my own comments system and decided it was time to move on to MySQLi.

What I am wondering is - am I doing this correctly?

Am I freeing and closing the results where necessary? Am I missing anything?

(also what enables syntax highlighting on this site? code sample button does nothing)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'comments');
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO comments (topid, body, user, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('isii', $id, $comment, $userid, $mod);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
else
{
    $mysqli->close();
    echo '{"status":0,"error":'.json_encode('Database Error - Please try again.').'}';
    return;
}
$mysqli->close();
```

and here is what I am doing for my 'while' loops :

```
$comments = array();

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'comments');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT user.id as userid, user.name, comments.id, comments.body, comments.dt FROM comments JOIN user ON comments.user = user.id where comments.postid = ? and comments.topid=0 and comments.active=1 ORDER BY comments.id DESC Limit ?, ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $postid, $offset, $limit);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
}

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    $comments[] = new Comment($row);
}

$res->free();
$mysqli->close();

return $comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

> am I doing this correctly?

Definitely no.

There is one thing about *API* functions, misunderstood by PHP users. **They aren't intended to be used in the raw form right in the application code.**
Despite of all the wrong examples you can find over internet, you have to create or adopt a **database abstraction library** which will do all the dirty job behind the scenes.

What it have to be like:

```
include 'db.php'; 
// if you don't mind to scroll a couple screens to the right yourself, 
// please be polite to ones whom you ask to - split your code, make it readable
$sql = "SELECT user.id as userid, user.name, comments.id, comments.body, comments.dt 
        FROM comments JOIN user ON comments.user = user.id 
        where comments.postid = ? and comments.topid=0 and comments.active=1 
        ORDER BY comments.id DESC Limit ?, ?"
return $db->getAll($sql, $postid, $offset, $limit);
```

Instead on saving on meaningful lines of code, save on the useless repeated ones.

```
include 'db.php'; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (topid, body, user, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$res = $db->query($sql, $id, $comment, $userid, $mod);
if (!$res)
{
    echo json_encode(array("status" => 0, 
                           "error"  => 'Database Error - Please try again.');
}
```

Some minor notes

For some very strange reason you are not setting charset for the insert.
You are using json wrong way.
Closing and freeing is just unnecessary.